# Allow Win32_LogicalDisk for regular users

Tags: permissions, wmi

I am trying to set permissions for regular (non admin) users (group DOMAIN\Domain users) for getting general information about system and disk remotely through WMI.

I set permissions for that in "Computer Management" / "Services and Applications" / "WMI Control". I set "Execution Methods", "Enable Account", "Remote Enable" on REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME.
Moreover I added "Domain users" group to the local "Distrubuted COM Users".

Then I run PowerShell request on LOCAL_COMPUTER_NAME which returns correct response:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME
```

Then I run another PowerShell request which returns error:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME

Get-WMIObject : Provider failure
```

This error equal to the code: **0x80041004**

But if I run this request from administrator account then run request from a regular user account I get correct response.

I tried to set all checkboxes on root WMI permissions (with inheritance), but it did not help. I understand that I have to set some additional permissions, but which permissions? Google did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll not believe but reboot of computer helped!